# Как вырезать "№Дн028" из строки?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Помогите с регуляркой, которая из строки:

```
Заявка: № 142898 от Аптека №Дн028 г.Кривой Рог, ул.К.Маркса, 19 (Задача №239735)
```

выберет только №Дн028.
Критерии поиска - обязательно "№", одна или несколько букв, одна или несколько цифр - всё без пробела, фраза отделена пробелами слева и справа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [*preg_match()*](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php) *(или preg_match_all() - если нужно найти все вхождения в подстроку)*:

```
$str = 'Заявка: № 142898 от Аптека №Дн028 г.Кривой Рог, ул.К.Маркса, 19 (Задача №239735)';

preg_match('~№\pL+\d+~iu', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr); // №Дн028
```

Answer (score 1):

Имеем строку:

```
$string = 'Заявка: № 142898 от Аптека №Дн028 г.Кривой Рог, ул.К.Маркса, 19';
```

И следующее регулярное выражение:

```
preg_match('/№[а-яА-Я]+[0-9]+/', $string, $matches);
```

*Подробности регулярного выражения*:

- `№` - первый символ всегда №
- `[а-яА-Я]+` - одна или более русских букв разного регистра
- `[0-9]+` - одна или более цифра в диапазоне от `0 до 9`

Далее выводим на экран

```
print_r($matches);
```

В результате получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => №Дн028
)
```